# Connect GKE cluster from DO cluster by using kubeconfig (not using gcloud)

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, digital-ocean

I have a cluster on Digital Ocean. The API of my project is in  DO. My image is from google/cloud-sdk:alpine and also I installed gke-gcloud-auth-plugin with the following command

```
gcloud components install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin
```

I have another cluster on Google Kubernetes Engine. I want to create, list, delete pods on gke cluster from my api which is in DO. I use kubernetes go client. I give the kubeconfig file of gke cluster to go client. But when I try to do an operation (like listing pods) I get the following error:

```
 cred.go:145] print credential failed with error: Failed to retrieve access token:: failure while executing gcloud, with args [config config-helper --format=json]: exit status 1
2023/04/04 07:28:21 code: get_pod_error, error: Get "https://..../api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/cloud-flow-80117068-9715-4374-b91b-799472d647be": getting credentials: exec: executable gke-gcloud-auth-plugin failed with exit code 1
```

I used the same method to create or delete pods on another cluster in DO and worked successfuly.

Briefly I want to connect GKE cluster from DO cluster by using kubeconfig file of GKE
Is there anyone who encounter with the same problem?
Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solved like following:

1: Create a secret with a token and service account. Then associate them.
2: Create a clusterrole (give necessary permissions) and clusterrolebinding. Associate them. 
3: Associate the service account and clusterrolebinding.

Now you can use the token to connect gke cluster without using gke-gcloud-auth-plugin. 
If I dont use the token argument, the output is:

[image]

But , if I use the token, it works successfully
[image]

Also the go code that uses token and prints the pods is like following:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    v1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
)

func main() {
    // Path to the kubeconfig file
    kubeconfigPath := "/home/latif/.kube/config"

    // Build the configuration from the kubeconfig file
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", kubeconfigPath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error building config from kubeconfig: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Set the authentication token
    config.BearerToken = "my_token"

    // Create a new Kubernetes client
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error creating Kubernetes client: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Get the list of pods in the default namespace
    pods, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("default").List(context.Background(), v1.ListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error getting pods: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Print the name of each pod
    for _, pod := range pods.Items {
        fmt.Println(pod.Name)
    }
}
```